# I can't play audio from URL by MediaPlayer Android

Tags: android, url, audio, media-player

I have some problem with playing audio from url, namely I get two following exceptions:

```
E/MediaPlayer(3387): error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(3387): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

In my code, I declare a MediaPlayer object and String with URL

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
String url ="http://ciacho090.wrzuta.pl/audio/31h2JLMRCE7/eminem_soldier.mp3";
```

In my MainActivity, I initialize mMediaPlayer by default constructor and set stream type

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Then I set source on url and request async prepare catching possibility exceptions by this code:

```
try
        {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
                }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

finally I set onPreparedListener:

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
            {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

I get above exceptions and the music doesn't play. In Manifest, I have declared these permissions and min sdk version to 8

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> //i know- it's unneccesary
```

Maybe settings in manifest are cause of issues or url link to music file. I don't know whether it's capable to progressive download. Maybe can You give me some link? And why it doesn't work?

Comment: That appears to be a html page. MediaPlayer doesn't know how to play html pages. Check in the browser or use wget, etc.: http://ciacho090.wrzuta.pl/audio/31h2JLMRCE7/eminem_soldier.mp3 If you can get a link to an actual mp3 it should work.

Comment: I can download the mp3 from http://ciacho090.wrzuta.pl/audio/31h2JLMRCE7/eminem_soldier.mp3 by program similar to wget (Flashget 3.7) and my application still doesn't work.

Comment: All I know is it won't work from what you have posted. The server is returning HTML. If you have tried something else then you should either update your question or post a new question.

Comment: I haven,t tried something else, maybe someone can paste some tested link, then i will be know that it is not fault caused by link?

Comment: Change the URL to this: http://ia700200.us.archive.org/1/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3

Comment: Ok it works, but how do i know which urls can i add and which not?

Comment: The server must respond with an actual mp3, not html. There are many ways to check that but the easiest is just to go to it in your browser. Can you see the difference between the link that works and the one that doesn't work? The one that works resolves to an actual mp3 you can play and download, not an html page with an embedded player. I've added my answer as well for completeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL is returning html. `MediaPlayer` doesn't know anything about playing HTML pages. Just because it ends in `.mp3` doesn't mean it is an mp3.

You can check this easily by just visiting this page in a browser:

http://ciacho090.wrzuta.pl/audio/31h2JLMRCE7/eminem_soldier.mp3

Here's a "real" mp3 you can test with:

http://ia700200.us.archive.org/1/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3

In short: make sure you are passing a url that returns an mp3 or other supported audio format.

Comment: Thanks Ken, You help me a lot.

Comment: Ken Wolf also have a look at my question plz. http://stackoverflow.com/q/31162314/3496570